# Get output of hidden layer during classification task

Tags: python, output, classification, conv-neural-network

I have a question.

Working with CNN, there is a way to get output of an hidden layer during classification?
Example:

```
common_input = layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))    
x = model0(common_input) #model0 is a pretrain model on imagenet
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
p = layers.Dense(768, activation="relu")(x)
p = layers.Dropout(0.3)(p)
p = layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax", name="fc_out")(p)
model = Model(inputs=common_input, outputs=p)
```

My task is classification; so if I have 2000 images I will get a matrix 2000x8. If I need the output of layer dense, there is a way to get a matrix 2000x768 (both in the same computation)?

Thanks

Comment: Please your question and add information about the framework you are using.

Comment: @bezirganyan My question is **there is a way to get a matrix 2000x768 (both in the same computation)?**
I'm using tensorflow and keras.